# Tree level generation using queue

Tags: c, tree

What algorithm generally would one use to generate a tree level using a queue to hold reachable but unexpanded trees?

For clarification, add `FOO` new nodes into the next tree level of the given tree with each tree node of the new level contained within the queue.

Attempt of achieving this...

```
void generate_level(tree t, queue q)
{
    t_node new, old;
    old = get_t_node_child(get_data(t));

    for (int i = 0; i < FOO; i++)
    {
        init_t_node(&new, temp, get_level(t)+1);
        if (get_t_node_child(get_data(t)) == NULL)
        {
             set_t_node_child(old, new);
             add(q, new);
             old = new;
        }
        else
        {
            old = new;
        }
    }
}
```

t_node struct:

```
struct t_node_int
{
    void *data;     
    int level;      
    t_node parent;
    t_node child;   
    t_node sibling;
};
```

Comment: New is a keyword, try using a different name for starters

Comment: @Rostin : not in C it isn’t.  I tend to avoid it anyway, but `new` is not a keyword in C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ah my bad. ^_^

Comment: What kind of tree are you using? can we see the t_node struct?